# Which jQuery slider do you suggest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, suggestions

I need a slider like [this one](http://valogiannis.com/stackoverflow/scrollto/scrolltoexample.htm) . As you can see when it's on the last part, and is needed to show the first again, it scrolls fastly to the left. I want a slider that doesn't have this behavoir. What do you suggest? All I found do the same thing. If you can find a solution for the above slider I have an open question at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073704/jquery-scroll-fast-return).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've usually found that finding a jQuery slider that fits one's needs is a losing battle - there always ends up being one tiny little dealbreaker. I'm considering just building my own from scratch.

Comment: You don't need to have the question open on both sites. If you ask here, we will answer it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nivo Slider is my Favorite: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can check this web sites it has nice jquery slider http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials